# Validate params properly in Next.JS app router with searchParams

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, next.js13

I want to render the page on build and therefore I need to validate params properly in Next.JS app router with searchParams.

This is what I want to do: I have the `/gallery` page, here I show from every photo a main image - the `coverImage`. Then when I click on a photo I want to display on the `/gallery/[id]` page more photos of the same kind. Thats what I try to show with my working example on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/falling-waterfall-8zn334?file=%2Fapp%2Fgallery%2Fpage.tsx%3A11%2C56).

As you can see my /gallery page:

```
import Link from "next/link";
import images from "../config/Gallery";
import { Fragment } from "react";
import Image from "next/image";

export default function Gallery({
  searchParams,
}: {
  searchParams: { [key: string]: string | string[] | undefined };
}) {
  const selectedImage = searchParams.id as unknown | number;

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-wrap justify-center">
      <Link href={"/"}>Homepage </Link>
      {images.map((image) => {
        selectedImage === image.id;
        return (
          <Fragment key={image.id}>
            <div className="px-5 py-5">
              <Link href={`/gallery/${image.id}`}>
                <Image
                  src={image.coverImage}
                  title={image.title}
                  alt={image.title}
                  placeholder="blur"
                  height={200}
                />
                <h1>Click on Image! </h1>
              </Link>
            </div>
          </Fragment>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I match the selected Image with my `searchParams.id`. The id in my interface is of type number. But when I change the searchParams to number and remove the `unknown | number` type from my selectedImage I get the error:

`Property 'id' does not exist on type 'number'`

My workaround is to use this types for searchParams.

```
searchParams: { [key: string]: string | string[] | undefined };
```

And then add as unknown | number to const selectedImage and it works but this is very hacky and not the correct way I guess.

Comment: search params values are string/null values, and the way your casting the type is just to make typescript happy, but the type itself still string, i'm not sure how it works, unless image.id is string but you treating it as number. the solution is to use parseInt()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query params are always of `string` type (if available).

As such the below type for `searchParams` does make sense:

```
searchParams: { [key: string]: string | string[] | undefined };
```

---

This however do not make sense:

```
const selectedImage = searchParams.id as unknown | number;
```

Since you want `selectedImage` as `Number` type, its better to do it runtime (rather than forcing the type on TypeScript).

```
const selectedImage = Number(searchParams.id)
```

> - Number("123"); // returns the number 123
> - Number("unicorn"); // NaN
> - Number(undefined); // NaN
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number

In case `searchParams.id` is not available, you can use a dummy value (so you wont get `NaN`),

```
const selectedImage = Number(searchParams.id ?? -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want get url params element you should try  this solution

import:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
```

usage:

```
const {query: { symbol }} = useRouter();
```